# Explicação e Tradução para inglês de "integrante titular"

Tags: significado, tradução, tradução-inglês

Na *Folha de São Paulo* podemos ler [aqui](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2016/04/1762748-pmdb-tera-maioria-em-comissao-do-impeachment-no-senado.shtml) que:

> [...] o PMDB terá direito a indicar o maior número de integrantes titulares para o colegiado.

Alguém poderia me explicar o que é um *integrante titular*?

Dá para traduzir *integrante titular* para inglês?

Comment: integrantes titular is a full-fledged member of the impeachment committee. Here, the committee to impeach Roussef. Full-fledged members of the impeachment committee. That said, in English, we wouldn't say it but we would say substitute member for suplente. Dá para traduzir tudo ao inglês, é só saber....não se diz holder members, disculpa.....we would just say: member and substitute member.

Comment: Os comentários são para pedir esclarecimentos ou para sugerir melhorias. Evita responder em perguntas, @AndréLyra .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Integrantes* são aqueles que *integrarão* a comissão, isto é, que dela farão parte.

*Titulares* é usado em oposição a *suplentes*, i.e., será titular quem ocupar de facto o cargo, ou seja, quem puder participar nos trabalhos e votar. Os *suplentes* só passarão a titulares se se abrir uma vaga — se algum dos titulares deixar a comissão antes de esta ser dissolvida. Da mesma forma, num jogo de futebol há os titulares (*starting players*) e os suplentes (*substitutes*).

Portanto, os *(senadores) integrantes titulares* são aqueles que integrarão efetivamente a comissão, não apenas como suplentes.

Answer (score 4):

*Integrante titular* is a full-fledged member of the impeachment committee. Here, the committee to impeach Roussef. Full-fledged members of the impeachment committee. That said, in English, we wouldn't say *full-fledged member*, but we would say *member* for *integrante titular*, and *substitute member* for *suplente*.

Comment: Lambie, I removed a large chunk of your answer: it may make sense in your comment above, but not in this answer. I only got what you meant by it after I read the comments above.

Comment: My answers are usually pretty clear. I have no idea what you mean. I just happened to post it under comments and as an answer. The content is basically the same in both.